# Prove that Galois theory for finite $k$-algebras implies classical Galois theory.

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

For a field extension $K\subset L$, an $K$-algebra $A$ is *splitted* by $L$ if $A$ is algebraic over $K$ and every minimal polynomial of elements in $A$ over $K$ splits in $L$ into distinct linear factors.

> **Theorem 1.** Let $K\subset L$ be a finite Galois extension of fields. Write $\operatorname{Gal}(L/K)\operatorname{-Set}_f$ for the category of finite $\operatorname{Gal}(L/K)$-sets and $\operatorname{Split}_K(L)_f$ for the category of finite $K$-algebras splitted by $L$. The functor $$\operatorname{Hom}K(-,L):\operatorname{Split}_K(L)_f\to \operatorname{Gal}(L/K)\operatorname{-Set}_f$$ is a contravariant equivalence of categories.

This is Theorem 2.4.3 in the book *Galois Theories* by Janelidze. He then commented below.

> The contravariant equivalence implies the existence of an isomorphism between the lattice of subobjects $M$ in $$K\rightarrowtail M\rightarrowtail L$$ in $\operatorname{Split}_K(L)_f$ and the lattice of quotients $\operatorname{Hom}_K(M,L),$ $$\operatorname{Gal}(L/K)\simeq\operatorname{Hom}_K(L,L)\twoheadrightarrow \operatorname{Hom}_K(M,L)\twoheadrightarrow\operatorname{Hom}_K(K,L)$$ in $\operatorname{Gal}(L/K)\operatorname{-Set}_f$. This is precisely the classical Galois theorem.

From the categorical equivalence I can deduce that the composition of inclusions $K\subset M\subset L$ maps injectively to composition of surjections $$\operatorname{Hom}_K(L,L)\twoheadrightarrow \operatorname{Hom}_K(M,L)\twoheadrightarrow\operatorname{Hom}_K(K,L)$$ where the maps are just the restriction maps. The second surjection just says that the set $\operatorname{Hom}_K(M,L)$ is not empty. However, How am I able to establish a 1-1 correspondence between the surjections of the $\operatorname{Hom}$ sets and canonical surjections $\operatorname{Hom}_K(L,L)\to\operatorname{Hom}_K(L,L)/H$ for some subgroup $H$? What exactly does he mean by "isomorphism of lattices"? I understand the first lattice as inclusions, but what is the second lattice it corresponds to? Please use as little Galois theory as possible as I am trying to deduce it from this "generalized" theorem.